# is it efficient way to write closure in cellForRowAtIndexPath in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

for example I have 2 actions in cell and cell call closures when events fire from cell. I written code as bellow. I have query that is that closure creates only once or new closure created and assign when cellForRowAtIndexPath method calls.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let therapies = therapySections?[indexPath.section].therapies

    let cell = TableViewCell.cellFor(tableView, for: indexPath, with: therapies?[indexPath.row])

    cell.deleteRowCallBack = { [weak self] (selectedCell, synchronizedObjectId) in

        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }
    }

    cell.editRowCallBack = { [weak self] (selectedCell, synchronizedObjectId) in

        guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

or I have to create variable of closures and then assign to respective cell closures.

Comment: You can use delegate pattern with protocol.

Comment: Just asking for clarification, but how are these callbacks called? Are they attached to actions in the table view cell and once a button is clicked for example, you call this completion? 
If that is the case then using delegates is definitely the better approach

Comment: Basically it is but it's unclear what happens in the cell.

Comment: Vadian, Alan S in cell those closure call when click on buttons in cell like delete, edit, etc. delegate is always better way, and I am confused that either assign direct closure or create global variable for those closures and assign to cell closure variables.